# AVX2 rotate vector

Tags: assembly, masm, avx2

My platform is MASM64, AVX2.
I need to perform a rotate operation over the YMM registry as follow:

> || A0 || A1 || A2 || A3 || = > || A1 || A2 || A3 || A0 ||

where Ai is a qword.
I was not able to find any documentation's reference to the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like `vpermq` with a control byte of `0x39`, unless you've numbered the qword in an unexpected order (I'm used to seeing them drawn with 0th one as the rightmost)

Comment: thank you a lot, just want to add that if you need to rotate other side control byte will be 093h